# How to sum up the matching elements of arrays and count number of them in C

Tags: arrays, count

I need to get the program to find the matching values from the two arrays, sum of matching elements and their count. I seem to have done the first one but the second is giving me the wrong total. It should be 25 but I get 14. Finally I could not figure out how to get the count of the matching elements. All help is appreciated. My code is below.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7,8};
    int b[] = {1,2,3,4,6,7,8};
    int i,j,sum,count;

    for (i=0;i<7;i++)

    {   

    enter code here
    for (j=0;j<7;j++)
    {
       if (a[i] == b[j])
    printf("Numbers match: %d\n",a[i]);
    }
    }
    printf("--------------------------------\n");
    if ( i == j )
    sum= (i+j);
    printf("Sum: %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Assumes both arrays are the same size. You need to set all counters (sum, count) to a known value (0), otherwise, will have garbage in them.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,7,8};
    int b[] = {1,2,3,4,6,7,8};
    int i,j,sum=0,count=0;
    int numElements = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

    for (i=0;i<numElements;i++)
    {   
        for (j=0;j<numElements;j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                printf("Numbers match: %d\n",a[i]);
                count++;
                sum += a[i];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("--------------------------------\n");

    printf("Sum: %d\n",sum);
    return 0;
    }
```